# Is there a way to embed a custom font in Pagedown?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, editor

I need to paste in some sample code.  However, the code needs a font that has the specific unicode characters in it. The default font that Stackoverflow is using does not support the characters (APL glyphs).

Is there any way to embed a custom font?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. You'll have to use an image instead

Comment: Really? Stackoverflow sends UTF-8, and browsers should fall back if the font is short on characters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do math or math-like things, you might consider using http://mathbin.net/, in which you can type latex-math, and link it in your question/answer.

EDIT: there is also something called https://math.stackexchange.com/ ;) Maybe I should be suggesting that around there.

Comment: Using latex or mathjax (ascii syntax) is a nice idea.  However lacking the true embedded font doesn't allow easy copy and paste of sample code to and from the interpreter.  Evryy example would need to run through some middleware tranlation code.  :-(